# How do I stop google from crawling my Bitly Branded short domain?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot, google-crawlers

The problem is that we are using bitly branded short domains as a url shortener. Our branded short domain is d.so.city

Now whenever I search site:so.city on google, all the d.so.city links appear even before the genuine site urls. I don't want the bitly url's to be crawled. I know this can be easily done through robots.txt for the subdomain but we dont have access to subdomain's robots.txt file as it is fully linked with bitly.

I have also tried parameter blocking from google webmaster but no luck there also. I have also gone through Bitly documentation but couldn't find anything relevant there as well.

Below is the snapshot of how my site search looks right now:

[image]
I dont want these d.so.city links to appear on google search. It will be really appreciated if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a no index meta tag for each of the pages under d.so.city should do the trick.

To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site, place the following meta tag into the  section of your page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

If you're telling Google webmasters for parameter blocking, it is essentially trying to block stuff that it will find after crawling a particular page.

Ref: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en